# Sony Camera Remote API available over USB on new models?

Tags: camera, sony, sony-camera-api

While Sony teases new camera models to customers (UMC-R10C, UMC-S3C) and mentions both API access and USB connectivity (rather than wifi) - the Sony Camera Remote API currently only mentions wifi. Is there any information on how to use those upcoming cameras? Some 'selected' developers are integrating them already (see: http://diydrones.com/profiles/blogs/sony-3dr-announce-new-enterprise-camera-for-solo) but independent developers are left in the dark.

Will the API be the same as the current Camera Remote API?
What kind of USB connection will it have. Just a USB network interface?

Answer (score 3):

+1 on question/request. A lot of DIY'ers are interested in (buying and) controlling Sony cameras via USB. WiFi in 'noisy' environments is problematic.